# unixtime to datetime in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to convert unix_time to date time format in pyspark(databricks).

sample data(test_data)

```
id       unix_time
169042   1537569848
```

the script which I created is

```
test_data= test_data.withColumn('end_time', from_utc_timestamp(test_data.unix_time, 'PST'))
```

I am getting the following error :-

> due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires timestamp type,
>   however, '`unix_time`' is of bigint type

**Update**

**output**

unix_time=1537569848

end_time=2018-09-21 22:44:08 ( is this UTC time? is unix time format by default utc time?)

end_time_ct= 2018-09-21T22:44:08.000+0000 ( how do I convert the above time to central time?)

**My current query**

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

test_data= test_data.withColumn('end_time', from_unixtime(test_data.unix_time ,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))

test_data = test_data.withColumn('end_time_ct', from_utc_timestamp(test_data.end_time ,"CT"))

display(test_data)
```

Comment: I think you need this function [`from_unixtime`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dateformat#pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime) and not `from_utc_timestamp`

Comment: test_data= test_data.withColumn('end_time', from_unixtime(test_data.unix_time, 'PST')) 
the new column end_time is returning null values

Comment: remove the second parameter `'PST'`, I don't think it is the good parameter with this function. Go see the link, they give a good example on how to set the timezone as well

Comment: please check update, the CT timezone update isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timezone configuration for the `SparkSession` can be set to `CST` or `CDT`

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "CST")

test_data = test_data.withColumn(
    'end_time', 
    from_unixtime(test_data.unix_time , 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
)
```

`from_unixtime` is returning the timestamp in default `timeZone` set for the 
`SparkSession` which can be verified by running:

```py
spark.conf.get('spark.sql.session.timeZone')
```

I suspect that its `CEST` because `2018-09-21 22:44:08` is 2 hours ahead of `UTC`.